# глюки с пространством имен std

Tags: c++, c++builder

Транслятор Borland C++ Builder 6.0.

Сижу тихо, пишу код:

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
return 0;
}
```

при трансляции в строке

```
using namespace std;
```

выдает ошибку

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(2): E2282 Namespace name expected

если переставить первые две строки местами вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
return 0;
}
```

то все транслируется.

Почему ругается на объявление пространства имен?

Comment: @epsicoca1 Я думаю, что ошибка имеет место в самом заголовочном файле. Например, в заголовке может стоять проверка #if defined( __cplusplus )  и т.д. И директива перед заголовком влияет на поиск имен в самом заголовке. Может быть заголовок может иметь собственную такую директиву. То есть причину ошибки надо искать внутри заголовка.:)

Comment: @epsicoca1 Также, насколько я знаю, например, в BC++ 5.0 был неправильный поиск неквалифицированных имен, когда использовалась using директива. Может быть в BC++ 6.0  его не исправили:)

Comment: Как раз ошибка возникает, когда using namespace std; стоит первой строкой. То есть заголовочный файл еще не начал обрабатываться.

Comment: @epsicoca1 Номер строки в сообщении об ошибке - 2. Я думаю, что это касается строки с заголовочными файлом, или нет?

Comment: Ошибка возникает в строке using namespace std;

Comment: Это может быть результатом того, что ошибка "всплыла" вверх из-за несоответствия внутри заголовка. Вам надо смотреть заголовок. Я думаю, что именно он является причиной ошибки, то есть те директивы и объявления, которые включены в заголовок.

Comment: если убрать строку #include, то ошибка все равно возникает

Comment: Что, без заголовка тоже выдает ошибку?:)

Comment: да, без директивы #include тоже возникает ошибка

Comment: Я понял причину ошибки. Компилятор проверяет, определено ли имя, используемое в директиве. Когда вы включаете  заголовок перед директивой, то внутри заголовка это имя определено.

Comment: нет, если после #include два раза поставить using, то все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина ошибки заключается в том, что данный компилятор проверяет имя, используемое в директиве `using`: определено оно или нет.

Когда перед директивой включен заголовок, то, похоже этот заголовок определяет имя `std`, например, следующим образом

```
#if defined( __cplusplus )
namespace std
{
```

и поэтому директива, следующая после заголовка, может на него ссылаться.

Когда же заголовок не включен, то получается, что имя `std` не определено, и использование его в `using` директиве компилятор рассматривает как ошибку.

Comment: Действительно, похоже на то. Во всяком случае когда я вставил первой строкой namespace std{};, то трансляция пошла без ошибок. Спасибо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Вы можете провести простой тест. Уберите все заголовки и перед using директивой вставьте предложение namespace std {}. Точка с запятой не ставится в конце этого предложения.

Comment: Уже так сделал. Все заработало.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Тогда ставьте "птичку" моему ответу, что считать его закрытым.:)

Comment: Вроде поставил. Я тут недавно, не разобрался еще со всеми правилами.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Надеюсь, это не последний раз.:)

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, не только я запнулся на пространстве имён С++, поэтому разрешите предоставить объяснение Герберта Шилдта в книге "С++. Руководство для начинающих": Приложение Б. Использование устаревшего С++ компилятора. При использовании современного компилятора у вас не должно быть проблем с компиляцией программ из этой книги. В этом случае вам вообще не понадобится информация, представленная в настоящем приложении. Как разъяснялось выше, программы, приведенные в этой книге, полностью соответствуют стандарту ANSI/ IS0 для С++ и могут быть скомпилированы практически любым современным С++-компилятором, включая Visual С++ (Мiсrosoft) и С++ Builder (Borland). Но если вы используете компилятор, созданный несколько лет назад, то при попытке скомпилировать наши примеры он может выдать целый список ошибок, не распознав ряд новых С++-средств. И в этом случае не стоит волноваться. Для того чтобы эти программы заработали со старыми компиляторами, нужно внести в них небольшие изменения. Чаще всего старые и новые С++-программы отличаются использованием двух средств: заголовков и npoстранств имен." Я ПОКОРОЧЕ ОПИШУ: Новая версия компилятора не требует указывать расширение имён файлов заголовков(.h), НО ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО требуется объявлять пространство имён std. ЕСЛИ У ВАС ПРИ КОМПИЛЯЦИИ возникают ошибки с указанием на эти строки, ЗНАЧИТ У ВАС СТАРАЯ ВЕРСИЯ КОМПИЛЯТОРА, и ему надо указывать так:

#include <iostream.h> // указываем расширение имени файла заголовков .h

// using namespace std; - исключаем строку, объявляющую область пространства имён языка С++, необходимых для новой версии языка и компилятора.