# глюки с пространством имен std (продолжение)

Tags: c++, c++builder, language-lawyer

Недавно задавал вопрос про пространство имен в BCB 6.0.

[глюки с пространством имен std](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457364/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-std)

Вроде ответ нашелся.

Но тут же возникло продолжение вопроса - как надо правильно применять декларацию using namespace std; чтобы не возникало описанных проблем.

То есть для некоторых трансляторов можно использовать using namespace std; до первого объявления namespace std{}. А для некоторых трансляторов обязательно сначала написать namespace std{}, и только потом можно использовать using namespace std;.

Но ведь нехорошо в своем коде писать пустое объявление namespace std{} только для того, чтобы использовать using namespace std;

Вопрос:

1. А как надо по стандарту?

Comment: По *де-факто* стандарту `using` директивы идут после `include`'ов. Придерживаясь этого элементарного «стандарта» у Вас более не возникнет проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно стандарту директива `uisng` является **объявлением**. Если вы, например, напишите

```
using namepsace std;
```

то данное предложение объявляет пространство имен `std` в текущей области объявлений.

В разделе *3.1 Declarations and definitions* стандарта C++ написано, что

> 1 A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a
>   translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous
>   declarations. If so, the declaration specifies the interpretation and
>   attributes of these names.

Там же в параграфе 2 написано:

> 2 A declaration is a definition unless ...it is .... a
>   **using-directive** (7.3.4).

И, соответственно, описание `using` директивы дается в разделе *7 Declarations*, где перечисляются и описываются объявления в языке C++.

Похоже, что старый компилятор C++ Builder 6.0 не рассматривает директиву как объявление и требует, чтобы используемое в директиве имя было предварительно объявлено в определении пространства имен.
Например,

```
namespace std {}
//...
using namespace std;
```

С моей точки зрения, имеют место баги компиляторов. С другой стороны, Стандарт C++ в этом отношении написан таким образом, что оставляет открытыми многие вопросы относительно using директивы. Поэтому я также считают, что стандарт C++ имеет дефект в описании using директивы, и по крайней мере должны быть внесены редакторские правки, чтобы убрать неоднозначность понимания.

Я поясню свою позицию.

В стандарте сказано (3 Basic concepts)

> 5 Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration

То есть каждое имя, обозначающее некоторую сущность, должно быть введено посредством объявления.

using директива - это бесспорно объявление. Какое имя оно объявляет? То имя, которое используется в using директиве.

То есть using директива вносит имя в область объявлений.

Можно рассмотреть аналогию с классами.  Данное предложение

```
class A;
```

является объявлением класса `A`. Оно вносит данное имя в область объявления. Но это не является определением класса `A`.

С другой стороны, предложение

```
class A {};
```

является не только объявлением, но и определением класса `A`. То есть оно не только вносит имя в область объявлений, тои указывает, какие члены содержит класс (в данном случае класс не имеет явно объявленных членов).

То же самое и using директивой.

```
using A;
```

объявляет имя `A` как имя пространства имен. Но оно не определяет, из каких членов это пространство имен состоит.

С другой стороны

```
namespace A {}
```

это объявление и определение пространства имен `A`.

Поиск имен в пространстве, обозначенном с помощью using директивы, никак не влияет на объявление самого пространства имен и на его определение, так как этот поиск зависит от того, является ли он поиском квалифицированных имен или нет.

Поэтому using директива может лишь объявлять то имя, которое указано в ее записи.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, по стандарту можно использовать `using namespace std;` и без того, чтобы пространство имён `std` было предварительно задекларировано.

Согласно [этой таблице](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), Borland C++ Builder (то есть, Embarcadero) поддерживает стандарт достаточно слабо. Вам придётся использовать для него обходной путь, но вообще-то (для компилятора, поддерживающего стандарт) это не должно быть нужно.

---

Обновление по результатам дискуссии с @Vlad from Moscow и @ixSci:

Кажется, что использование `using` перед `#include` (или явным определением пространства имён) всё же не разрешено. Компилятор gcc не считает это ошибкой, но такое поведение [висит как баг в их базе данных](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2006-10/msg00945.html). Компилятор clang [выдаёт предупреждение](https://goo.gl/Ayjl9g). Visual Studio 2012 молча компилирует.

Но мы пока не смогли найти нормативную ссылку.

Comment: Почему думаете, что стандарт разрешает такое поведение? По стандарту происходит поиск(lookup), а как поиск может завершиться положительно, если в видимом диапазоне пространство имён `std` нигде не может быть найдено?

Comment: @ixSci: Мне кажется, логика та же, что и в `class C;` — предварительная декларация. Но если хотите, поищу ссылку в стандарте.

Comment: `class C` это именно, что декларация — `using namespace ...` это использование, а не декларация(насколько я это понимаю)

Comment: @ixSci: Вот ещё [обсуждение на en.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841130/276994).

Comment: Свежий clang [выдаёт warning](https://goo.gl/Ayjl9g), gcc нет. Visual Studio 2012 тоже не диагностирует.

Comment: Не знаю, не вижу я в стандарте никаких запретов на такое поведение.   В любом случае, это настолько «corner case», что его рассмотрение только время отнимает, при нулевой пользе. Всё равно так никто не пишет.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, суть вопроса-то как раз «а как правильно по стандарту», а не «а как обычно делаете вы».

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Подключайтесь к дискуссии! Покамест вроде бы кажется, что `using` перед декларацией пространства имён неправильно, но мы не можем найти нормативную ссылку.

Comment: Мысли по результатам рассмотрения бага в базе данных GCC. Никто не гарантирует, что в данном конкретном хедере будет объявление namespace std{}. Получается, что о общем случае перед using namespace std надо писать namespace std{}.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Хм, вы правы, подключение хедера по сути ничего не гарантирует.